# Angular6 argument expression expected error

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm not sure at all how to resolve this after googling extensively, but basically I'm getting the following error with the follow app.module.ts:

Argument expression expected.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    NewsitemComponent,
    InputClearableComponent,
    CreditsComponent,
    CompanyPortfolioComponent,
    EspComponent,
    CcstComponent,
    SearchNewsPipe,
    AssumptionsComponent,
    JojoComponent,
    SectorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatIconModule,
    ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts'),
    MatButtonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [SearchNewsPipe],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

**edit:**

If I delete the trailing comma I get the following error instead:

',' expected.

No idea what's going on here.

Comment: Which trailing comma do you delete? Which line is the erroneous one?

Comment: right after imports. below browseranimations

Comment: ```ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts'))```

Comment: I suggest using an editor that supports syntax check and tslint to avoid running into simple syntax errors (which can be terribly hard to detect)

Answer (score 1):

i am myself new to this angular 6 but i can give you a hint like    ) is missing in forRoot line  maybe that is what giving you an error.

Comment: @yoursweater   if that solves your issue you can give it a green tick as accepted

Answer (score 0):

try this adding commas at the end , typescript has added new rules , so angular has to follow

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
DashboardComponent,
NewsitemComponent,
InputClearableComponent,
CreditsComponent,
CompanyPortfolioComponent,
EspComponent,
CcstComponent,
SearchNewsPipe,
AssumptionsComponent,
JojoComponent,
SectorComponent,
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
NgbModule.forRoot(),
MatFormFieldModule,
MatInputModule,
MatIconModule,
ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts'),
MatButtonModule,
AppRoutingModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
],
```

Comment: You are missing a d in 'declarations' and a trailing parenthesis after highcharts'). The comma after SelectorComponent is not needed.